# Counting sort in O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, complexity-theory, counting-sort

I have the following counting sort, but the space complexity is too high for me, I'm looking for a way to do it in space complexity of O(1)

```
MyCountingSort(A, B, k)
    for i = 0 to k
       do G[i] = 0
    for j = 0 to length[A]
        do G[A[j]] = G[A[j]] + 1
    for i = 1 to k
       do G[i] = G[i] + G[i-1]
    for j = length(A) to 1
       do B[G[A[j]]] = A[j]
       G[A[j]] = G[A[j]] - 1
```

Currently, the algorithm is allocating O(k) space.
Assuming `k<=A.length`, how I can improve the algorithm space complexity to O(1)?

Comment: Mind telling us what `A`, `B` and `k` represent?

Comment: Reverse engineered: A is the input array, k is the max value in A, and B is the output array

Comment: I believe counting sort is intrinsically O(k) space. If you need less space, then you need to either (A) know more details about the input, or (B) use an entirely different algorithm.  `k<=A.length` is insufficient to improve this.  Now if `k<<<A.length`, then you can make (small) improvements.

Comment: Oh wait, let me think. There might be tricks we can do with using A and B.... ah! Yes, we can use `B` as temporary scratch space, and skip the use of G _maybe_.

Comment: Counting sort with the runtime complexity and O(1) space complexity would make the world a happier place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `A` is your input array, `B` is your output array. Thus, `|A| = |B|`. I'm further assuming that `k` is the maximum number of values we might encounter (for instance, if `A` contains only positive numbers from *1* to *k* or from *0 to k-1*). It would help us if you specify this kind of details when asking a question, but I'm guessing that this is more or less what you are asking. :)

Since we have the very convenient additional constraint that `k <= |A|`, we can use our given arrays `A` and `B` as intermediate storage for our index array. Essentially, make `B` your `G` in your code and perform the **1st** and **2nd** loop on it. Then we make the cumulative additions (**3rd** loop).

Once we have finished this, we can copy `B` back to `A`. Finally, we overwrite `B` with our final sorted array (**4th** loop in your code).

This way, no memory is allocated apart from the input parameters already given. In general, the space complexity of an algorithm is defined as independent of the input of the algorithm. Since we are only recycling the input arrays and not allocating anything ourselves, this algorithm is indeed of *O(1)* space complexity.

Notice that in the general case (where `k` is not necessarily `<= |A|`), it will not be this easy. In addition, it is only because the output array `B` has already been provided to us as an input that we can make use of this "trick" of using it for our internal use and thus not have to allocate any new memory.

Comment: Any reason to assume k <= |A| ?

Comment: @phoxis He/she said so in their question.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that part. In that case when the input size is bounded, then it becomes O(1) in any case.

Comment: @phoxis Yes it does change the question quite a lot :) What do you mean the input size is bounded though? You mean the size of the values?

Comment: I mean, let's say, just for an example, `k` has a maximum value of `1000`. In that case the method will be `O(1)`. Because whatever it be the operations can be done in constant time, which is the time taken when `k=1000`. So using that argument, if we have `|A|` constant. whatever the value of `k` is, the space is O(1), even if you allocate another array like in the question. Correct me if I am wrong here please.

Comment: @phoxis Yes that is very true, but here we don't really have constant `|A|`, at least from OP's information. Since `k` is bounded by `|A| = n`, not by a constant value, the space complexity would be `O(k) = O(n)` in OP's code, if we know nothing else about `k`.

Comment: Yes, so essentially, I guess counting sort still will be O(k) in space even if the array `|B|` is used, and `|A|` is growing, because the space requirement does increase linearly. Here the output array is provided, which is actually increase with as `|A|` increases. If you don't provide the array, it has to get it from somewhere, so to do  the count , it still needs the O(k) space, when `|A|` is growing

Comment: @phoxis Yes indeed, normally a sorting algorithm is required to either produce a new sorted array, or perform in-place sorting on the input array. The fact that OP's algorithm somewhat unusually (in the theoretical world) provides both is what I assume is meant to strongly hint the student to make use of this "free" memory to "cheat" the system :)
In the general case, the space complexity is definitely not constant but will depend on `k` and `n`, depending on implementation.

Comment: Can you share what you mean by `Once we have finished this, we can copy B back to A. Finally, we overwrite B with our final sorted array (4th loop in your code).`? You just copy B back to A doing nothing?

Comment: @TheUnreal Well I suppose there are different ways you might generate the final output array in `B`. Here I'm suggesting that AFTER your 4th loop, you just copy `B` back to `A` (value by value, just add another for loop). Then, you can iterate through `A` and build `B` from it. Of course, this assumes that we are allowed to modify `A`, which might not be the case in some practical situations, but algorithmically, we can :)

Comment: Correction, BEFORE your 4th loop, you copy `B` into `A` and then you perform the final array generation (corresponding to your 4th loop) into `B`.